# Parse jolokia output with jq

Tags: json, regex, jq, wildcard, activemq-artemis

I have an Apache Artemis broker, of which I can get some management information through jolokia. This response is in json format; I also have jq to do "json stuff" with it.

```
curl -s -X GET --url 'http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:*'
```

This works; and provides a json response.

I want to make a kind of generic script to check some values from this response; hence a few questions:

(For ease of testing I stored the response in a file broker.json, normally I would just pipe the output from curl to jq or store it in a variable, depending on how often jq has to be called)

One of the keys I want to query I can get like this:

```
 jq '."value"."org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"broker1\""' broker.json
```

However, in a more generic script, I won't know the name of the broker (which is "broker1" here); is there some way I can wildcard the key like this: `"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"*\""` ? My attempts so far have not given me anything

The second question is a bit harder I think.
In the response there is a field that can be found by querying .request.timestamp
the value is in seconds since epoch.

On the broker are queues, and some of them might have messages; I want to find those that have messages older than, say, 5 minutes.

I can find one such object with this key:

```
  jq '."value"."org.apache.activemq.artemis:address=\"my.queue\",broker=\"broker1\",component=addresses,queue=\"my.queue\",routing-type=\"anycast\",subcomponent=queues"' broker.json
```

This object contains two keys I can use for this purpose:
- FirstMessageAge : age in ms
- FirstMessageTimestamp: timestamp in miliseconds since epoch.

How would I query for this? Ideally I'd like to get the answer "my.queue has messages older than X"; where my.queue can also be obtained from having the key "Address" or "Name"

Artemis uses Address and Queues as separate entities; for all practical purposes here, both have the same name.

I am trying to make a (simple) script that can periodically monitor the broker health (not too many messages on queues for too long, queues having consumers, stuff like that; which all can be gotten from this single rest call; I think that with the answers to above questions I should be able to figure out how to get this.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines, especially w.r.t. the second question.  At the very least, please post (or provide a pointer to) broker.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there some way I can wildcard the key like this: 
>   `"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"*\""`

The best way to match wildcards on key names is by using `with_entries` or `to_entries`.  Since you have not provided an example in accordance with the [MCVE](/help/mcve) guidelines, it's not clear exactly how you'd do so, but by analogy with the example you give, you could start with:

```
.value
| to_entries[]
| select(.key | test("^org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\".*\""))
| .value
```